# Recursion not working when called into another class

Tags: java

I wrote a recursive method which searches through a `BST`, compares the argument with the `string` property in the node, and returns the `int` property from that node if the strings match. The method works when it's called in it's own class, however, when I call it into a different class, it doesn't work anymore. So basically, the `private` part of the method works, its just the `public` part that's messing me up.

```
public int boka(String ime) {
    int bobo=boka(this.root,ime);
    return bobo;
}

private int boka(Node curr_root,String ime){
    if(curr_root==null){
        return -1;
    }

    boka(curr_root.left,ime);
    if(curr_root.info.ime.equalsIgnoreCase(ime)) {
        return curr_root.info.pobjede;
    }
    boka(curr_root.right,ime);
    return -1;
}
```

So basically, the `private` part works, however, when I call the recursion in another class using the `public`, it always returns `-1`.

In the other class, I'm doing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BinTree bt = new BinTree();

    int a = bt.boka("Djole");
```

I omitted the actual Node making and inserting, since I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: How are you trying to call it in the other class?

Comment: @GBlodgett I make an object of the class that the method is in, and then I call it like I would any other.
For instance since here the clas is called BinTree, 
I do this

BinTree bt = new BinTree();
int a =bt.boka("Djole"); 
 
Which works in the original class

Comment: Could you please include the class where the method is called?

Comment: @Jamesm Did it, my apologies

Comment: You say "the private part works" but I don't see how that's possible. You throw away the return values from the recursive method calls.

Comment: @DanielPryden That's actually true, and I have no idea why it's working now

Comment: @worstever: That means it *isn't working*. Good! You found where your problem is.

Comment: @DanielPryden Yeah, thank you!

Comment: FYI - `code formatting` is meant for *code* and for code-based keywords like `MySpecialClass` inside of regular text which are easier to interpret when they're formatted as code. It is not necessary / helpful to put code formatting on *every* programming-related term :)

Answer (score 1):

Your search will always return `-1` because you haven't properly implemented the search. I don't know why it's working when you run it in "it's own class" but you need to return the value of the recursive call; otherwise, you are just returning `-1` when the recursion is complete.

You can adjust your algorithm to this, and get it to work:

```
private int boka(Node curr_root,String ime){

    if(curr_root.left != null) return boka(curr_root.left,ime);

    if(curr_root.info.ime.equalsIgnoreCase(ime)) return curr_root.info.pobjede;

    if(curr_root.right != null) return boka(curr_root.right,ime);

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem like searching in a Binary Search Tree (or what else BST means?), it is more like an in-order traverse of an arbitrary binary tree.

You can make it working, just do not disregard the return values in the recursion:

```
private int boka(Node curr_root,String ime){
  if(curr_root==null) {
    return -1;
  }

  int ret=boka(curr_root.left,ime);
  if(ret!=-1) {
    return ret
  }

  if(curr_root.info.ime.equalsIgnoreCase(ime)) {
    return curr_root.info.pobjede;
  }

  return boka(curr_root.right,ime);
}
```